# Is there any other API to pull transaction data using Invoice data?

Tags: paypal

I am using REST APIs. I am trying to pull the transaction data especially transaction_id using Invoice_id.

In transaction search, I am able to see the transaction_id and invoice_id. However, I am unable to find the link to pull the transaction_id details using Invoice_id.

Is there any other API to pull transaction data using Invoice data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, there is no code, I am trying to get the link for transactional data based on the Invoice id

Answer (score 0):

No, PayPal isn't a database service. For historical transactions, best approach is to use the web account interface Reports function to download CSV files of the data and import this into your own database.

For keeping it current, store new transaction records immediately when a new transaction is created via the capture API call. Use a server-side create/capture if you aren't already (see the optional bullet #5 in the [Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide)

Comment: I am unable to download the files , is there any other way to pull the transaction data?

Comment: It's basic functionality: https://www.paypal.com/signin > Activity > All Reports > Activity download